# Activating the vibration in phone with JS

Tags: javascript, android, html, web-applications

I’m currently developing a HTML5 API based chat, making use of the `navigator.vibrator` method to activate the SmartPhone's vibration when getting a message. Everything works just fine when I have focus on the application browser tab (Google Chrome, in this case).

**The problem is:**
The vibration doesn’t work when I’m not using the browser (even though it's running in the background), and it also doesn’t work when the screen is turned off.

I really need the vibration to work no matter what.
Is there a way to activate this through JavaScript?

Follow My Code:

```
                                if (!document.hasFocus()) {
                                    window.focus();
                                    document.getElementById('s1').play();
                                    if (navigator.vibrate) {
                                        window.navigator.vibrate([500, 50, 500]);
                                    }
                                    else { alert('Não suporta vibração'); }

                                    alert('Você tem nova mensagem no chat...');
                                }
                                else { window.navigator.vibrate([500, 50, 500]); }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow :). Can you show us your code, please?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the return. I edited my question by putting the code.

Comment: One way to work around this would be to instead of using `navigator.vibrate` to show a push notification on a service worker. Push notifications can happen while the screen is off or the browser is minimized, and can cause vibration.